# How to fix windows 8 registry errors easily?

Tags: windows-8, windows-registry

How do can I fix all my windows 8 registry errors easily?

I am not an avid Windows or computer person but I am not computer illiterate either. I know of the **regedit.exe** but not sure how to go about using it.

I have not even attempted to try to fix this issue I'm having. I have something like 384 registry errors on my laptop, it is not running that good.

I'm sure this is most likely the reason why but not 100% sure. I need help badly, please.

Comment: Do you see any errors when doing stuff, or that is just what a program told you?

Comment: Programs that find "registry errors" are snake oil.  They often do more harm then good, those errors are not actually errors, and by fixing what the "errors" you found it will NOT help performance

Answer (score 2):

Welcome. The answer to your question on **how** to fix these errors would really be **just don't do it**...

There is no such a thing as **registry errors**! And I repeat, this whole registry errors buzz-word is simply marketing gimmicks or trying to fool users which aren't that experienced.

Of course, there may be sometimes problems and errors caused by misconfigured, or even malicious, registry entries. But...there's no magic way to find these things, not yourself and not through a program. And even worse, attempting to "clean" or "fix" it might result in a broken PC.

Here's from Microsoft themselves, in their [Microsoft support policy for the use of registry cleaning utilities](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2563254/microsoft-support-policy-for-the-use-of-registry-cleaning-utilities):

> Some products such as registry cleaning utilities suggest that the
>   registry needs regular maintenance or cleaning.  However, serious
>   issues can occur when you modify the registry incorrectly using these
>   types of utilities. These issues might require users to reinstall the
>   operating system due to instability. Microsoft cannot guarantee that
>   these problems can be solved without a reinstallation of the Operating
>   System as the extent of the changes made by registry cleaning
>   utilities varies from application to application.

And the same thing you can read from most of real computer specialists. Here are some from reputable sources:

- [Registry Cleaners: Digital Snake Oil](https://blog.malwarebytes.com/cybercrime/2015/06/digital-snake-oil/) from Malwarebytes
- [Why Using a Registry Cleaner Won’t Speed Up Your PC or Fix Crashes](https://www.howtogeek.com/171633/why-using-a-registry-cleaner-wont-speed-up-your-pc-or-fix-crashes/) from How-To Geek
- And you can also read about it in the [Registry cleaner Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registry_cleaner#Malware_payloads)

Comment: Much better; You answer the question, even if, it's a couple word answer but then explain the reason why.

Answer (score 2):

As Yisroel Tech correctly maintains, there are no registry errors, but there
are frequently registry left-overs, mostly created when uninstalling products.

Most uninstallations usually leave behind registry settings and files.
This is why it is recommended to use an advanced uninstaller rather than
only using the uninstaller that came with the product.
I usually recommend [Revo Uninstaller Freeware](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html).

These left-overs normally do not present a problem, unless the user
is in the habit of installing and uninstalling many products during
the year. I would suggest to install a temporary product
using [Sandboxie](https://www.sandboxie.com/), so no modifications are
done to the real registry and the sandbox can be cleaned out with
one click of a button, no uninstallation required.

Some products really abuse the registry. I have encountered products
which create thousands of entries in it, mostly large ones like Adobe.
Even if these entries are deleted when uninstalled, the deleted entries
still take their place in the registry and will slow it down.
This inefficient way in which registry deletions are done has given
registry cleaners their bad name.

Registry cleaning by itself is useless, unless followed by
registry defragmenting, reorganizing the registry to exclude the deleted
entries. This is normally not done by registry-cleaning products,
requiring other specialized products.

All these operations are very risky, and usually unnecessary.
They are only meaningful after some very unusual long-term usage of the computer.
Shaving off some microseconds for registry access is absolutely not worth
the risk involved in running these kind of products,
which I do not advise to anyone who is not an advanced user of Windows.

Comment: Great point about using a power uninstaller when uninstalling programs, I forget to mention that in my answer. But if I may disagree with the notion that unnecessary registry entries "will slow it down." This might have been the case with old Windows versions, but supposedly with Windows nowadays this wouldn't make any difference whatsoever.

Comment: @YisroelTech: I have no knowledge of any big changes in the internals of the registry - all I can say is that the interface looks identical to previous versions. I doubt that Microsoft will so easily decide to rewrite such a monumentally important repository and expose itself to critics about its most-solid-ever Windows version, but if it did, wouldn't we see some evolution in the API and UI?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the exact changes but here's from Wikipedia, "On Windows 9x computers, it was possible that a very large registry could slow down the computer's start-up time. However this is less of an issue with NT-based operating systems (including Windows XP and Vista), **due to a different on-disk structure of the registry, improved memory management and indexing**.[12] Furthermore, versions of Windows prior to Server 2003 may fail to start up, if the registry and kernel files are unable to fit within the first 16M of memory.[13]"

Comment: @YisroelTech: I'm not talking about ancient history. Let's stop this discussion.